# Javascript not adding-removing class

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, addition

I have an element I would like to start off by being hidden then show after 1 second. Here is my html and my css.

```js
function showLogo() {
  var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
  
  logo.classList.add( "notVisible" );
  logo.classList.remove( "visible" );
}

setTimeout(showLogo, 1000);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 580px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin:-25vh 0vh 0vh -25vh;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
}

.notVisible {
  opacity: 0;

}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">

<div id="logo" class="notVisible">
 <img id="rays" src="Images/PNGs/rayons.png">
 <img id="base" src="Images/PNGs/baseLogo.png">
 <img id="roue" src="Images/PNGs/roue.png">
 <img id="letters" src="Images/PNGs/title.png">
</div>
```

nothing is showing up. I had tried previously with jQuery and not working either so I decided to go with a full javascript solution but still not working. Any ideas why. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Instead of having classes, why not set the styling on the `#logo` itself?

Comment: Shouldn't the 2 classes be other way round ? you are setting it to 0 opacity in the `showLogo` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to add the `visible` class and to remove the `notVisible` one instead, like :

```
logo.classList.add( "visible" );
logo.classList.remove( "notVisible" );
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function showLogo() {
  var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
  
  logo.classList.add( "visible" );
  logo.classList.remove( "notVisible" );
}

setTimeout(showLogo, 1000);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 580px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin:-25vh 0vh 0vh -25vh;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
}

.notVisible {
  opacity: 0;

}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

<div id="logo" class="notVisible">
 <img id="rays" src="http://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/entityid/BBybXEH.img?h=50&w=50&m=6&q=60&u=t&o=t&l=f&f=png">
 <img id="base" src="http://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/entityid/BBybXEH.img?h=50&w=50&m=6&q=60&u=t&o=t&l=f&f=png">
 <img id="roue" src="http://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/entityid/BBybXEH.img?h=50&w=50&m=6&q=60&u=t&o=t&l=f&f=png">
 <img id="letters" src="http://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/entityid/BBybXEH.img?h=50&w=50&m=6&q=60&u=t&o=t&l=f&f=png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
logo.classList.add( "notVisible" );

logo.classList.remove( "visible" );
```

But it should be:

```
logo.classList.remove( "notVisible" );

logo.classList.add( "visible" );
```

Also your `<div id="container">` is missing a closing `</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct, however your function classes need to be switched. You need to be removing the notVisible and adding the visible class:

```
    function showLogo() {   
       var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

       logo.classList.add( "visible" );    
       logo.classList.remove( "notVisible" );

}   
    setTimeout(showLogo, 1000);
```